# Why does my SSD suddenly show up as HDD in the Task Manager?

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

My system’s 1 TB Western Digital M2 SSD shows up as an HDD in Task Manager. I did fresh Windows install couple days ago and it was showing just fine - SSD.

Today when I booted and checked - it says HDD... although in benchmarks and disk optimization it says it is SSD and performs as SSD too.

This just bothers me because I don’t know why it shows up as HDD in Task Manager. I tried uninstalling both drivers from device manager and the same results.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Windows has just launched this feature recently, odds are that you may experience such glitches.

Answer (score 3):

Windows classifies HDDs and SSDs by a special manufacturer serial/code ID.

This is easy to be messed-up with updates that could make tags fall into other category.

It is however irrelevant, it does not impact anything.

Don't worry, it will probably be fixed in future updates if it's reported enough.

Comment: Are you sure this won't affect auto-defrag and such?

Comment: No, it's just a tag. Should not influence at all how Windows works with the device.