# New SSD identified as HDD

Tags: windows-10, ssd, task-manager

I've bought cheap Verbatim Vx500 SSD for my media server's boot drive. Cloned system drive to  it with Aomei Partition Asisstant and everything works.
But today I've noticed that Windows10 thinks it is an HDD. It defrags it and in Task manager it aays directly type: HDD.
How do I switch it to SSD? Is there some registry key for it?

Comment: Similar: [Why does my SSD suddenly show up as HDD in the Task Manager?](https://superuser.com/q/1580405/432690)

Comment: It actually runs full defrag instead if Trim, so it is a problem. There is this problem with botched update now, so maybe it will be causing this. I'm downloading latest Insider build.

Comment: I've tried winsat disk - drive X, did change nothing.